# After installing from source wicd asks for password on boot?

Tags: software-installation, password, services, dialog, wicd

I decided that I wanted to try playing around with wicd, so I grabbed wicd-1.7.4 from launchpad, uninstalled the version I had installed with `apt-get`, and installed from source.

When trying to do the configure step I got some errors about gnome-shell, and to solve that I ran `./setup.py configure --no-install-gnome-shell-extensions`. I also got some errors about translation files so I deleted everything in the `wicd/po/` directory, which solved the issue.

After those steps, I was able to `./setup.py build` and `sudo ./setup.py install` without any issues.

Now, however, wicd asks for my password every single time I boot up, saying "wicd needs administrator privileges to access network cards" or something along those lines and then, after whatever I type in (even if it's my actual password) will tell me that the daemon could not be started correctly.

After navigating through all those dialogs however, I can just open the wicd icon in launchpad and it'll start as normal.

Even if I try to uninstall from source and then reinstall using `apt-get`, I still get these dialogs, which wicd did not create before I installed from source.

Does anybody know of solutions to this?

Comment: hi @Yaron, why did you delete your solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you apt-get remove --purge or dpkg -P (purge) your previous wicd install ? Not using --purge can leave old config files on your system.

Comment: @albertj I did purge